# pg_bulkload to convert data before persistence?

Tags: java, postgresql

As far as I read, `pg_bulkload` is the fastest way in `postgres` to batch large data into the DB (correct me if I'm wrong).

I want to process several tens of gigabytes from `CSV` format to DB. Each row in the csv file will represent a DB entry.
Important is that I have to transform and also to neglect some values of the csv file, like:

CSV:

```
date,stuff,nr
24/4/15,asdasd,1PERS/1PERS
```

Should result in:

```
2015-04-24,1/1
```

("date" transformed, "stuff" neglected, "nr" minimized)

Is that possible with `pg_bulkload`? If yes, could you give a transformation function on my example?

Comment: If you want to transform the data I'd consider an ETL tool - CloverETL, Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle. Performance isn't likely to be anywhere near as good though, so I'd be interested in seeing if anyone's done any sort of filters/transforms for `pg_bulkload`.